# Why is Hollywood not casting Jim Carrey anymore?

Tags: comedy, casting

Jim Carrey is a great comedian.

But why are we not seeing him in Hollywood movies anymore?

Any reason behind it.?

Comment: He was in a movie recently Dumb and Dumber 2..

Comment: But that was way back in 2014.

Comment: Why does no-one buy Stevie Wonder records any more? He's a great musician... Everyone has their time. Right now, he's making a [TV show](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7375404/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1)

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: How do we know he's still looking for work? Maybe he isn't looking for roles atm

Comment: May be @Azor-Ahai.. But i don't know, so i am asking for anyone knows..

Comment: “Jim Carrey is a great comedian” is your your opinion. He was a “popular” comedian during a time period where he suited people’s tastes, but tastes evolve and people loose popularity.

Comment: @NagarajJuro Yes, but your title as phrased suggests that he is trying to get cast, but no one will cast him.

Comment: At his age I don't think anyone wants to see him talking out of his butt (though he does that enough with his controversial statements).

Comment: Because he doesn't owe a bunch of money to the IRS like Nicholas Cage, so he doesn't need to make a bevy of crap movies to pay his debt ;)

Comment: This question sounds like a beginning of a clickbait article... -_-

Answer (score 17):

There are plenty of reasons, as shown in [this article on Looper](http://www.looper.com/36926/hollywood-wont-cast-jim-carrey-anymore/):

> - He's too much of a risk
> - He's not as much of a box office draw as he used to be
> - He stopped promoting *Kick-Ass 2*
> - His method acting got crazy during Man on the Moon
> - There may be issues getting him insured
> - He's been dealing with some personal issues
> - He's gone public with some pretty controversial beliefs
> - Jim Carrey no longer exists
> - He won't take a role unless it 'chooses' him
> - He hasn't been nominated for any major awards recently
> - And he's happy that way
> - He's busy mentoring the next generation of actors
> - He's been working behind the camera
> - He's been focused on making art for the past several years

Each of these reasons is discussed at length in the source article.

Most likely it's a combination of several of those factors, which means in the end he's too much trouble for a studio to bother with him.

Comment: Wasn't there also a recent controversy with him allegedly causing someone's death? (He was acquitted, as I recall.)

Comment: @F1Krazy That's one of the points in the list.

Comment: I would also add  "He starred in Polish crime movie True Crimes" that Poles in general criticized for "what movie? Never heard of it. Was it direct to some obscure internet service? He played who? Tadek? What?

Comment: That article is so well matched to this question that I'm beginning to think that OP is somehow connected to either looper or the author of that article..

Comment: @pipe Looper has ton of these stuff. soon they'll have *why holywood doesn't cast Hugh Jackman anymore*

Comment: @vishwa That is the main purpose of this forum, to get our doubts clarified.

Comment: @NagarajJuro do you have any connections with looper?

Answer (score 8):

In 2013 he [ended his relationship with his agents/managers](http://deadline.com/2013/10/jim-carrey-splits-with-eric-gold-and-jimmy-miller-609657/) Eric Gold and Jimmy Miller - they had represented him for the prior 25 years of his career.

The following year [he signed with Rick Yorn's LBI Entertainment](http://www.jimcarreyonline.com/recent/news.php?id=1987).

We are not privy to the discussions of possible work or contractual obligations each party had for the other during each contract.  However, many managers only make money when their stars make money, and so will push talent to accept work they might otherwise refuse.

Carrey is not in a position where he needs to accept work in order to meet his financial needs.

Further, the extraordinary decline in acting jobs does align strongly with the switch of management.

I suspect the main reason is that he simply doesn't want to do any of the parts which he could perform, and his manager is not pushing him to accept parts that he isn't interested in.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have provided, it's true Carrey has had some problems including the circumstances with his ex-girlfriend's murder (for which he has been cleared) along with taking some time to seek [controversial] artistic passions, --but Carrey is CURRENTLY still working in the film industry. He has been executive producing, *I'm Dying Up Here* AND later this year, he is returning to the small screen, set to star in the Showtime comedy Series, [*Kidding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidding_(TV_series)).

> **Jim Carrey will star in a new Showtime comedy series in his first
>   regular television role since his days on the 1990’s sketch show “In
>   Living Color,” Showtime announced Thursday**.
>
> The half-hour series is titled “Kidding,” in which Carrey will play
>   Jeff, a.k.a. Mr. Pickles,  an icon of children’s television, who also
>   anchors a multimillion dollar branding empire. But when his family
>   begins to implode, Jeff finds no fairy tale or fable or puppet will
>   guide him through this crisis, which advances faster than his means to
>   cope. Showtime has ordered a 10-episode first season.
>
> T**he role further expands Carrey’s relationship with Showtime, as he
>   currently executive produces the dramedy “I’m Dying Up Here,” which
>   was recently renewed for a second season.**
>
> The project will also reunite Carrey with “Eternal Sunshine of the
>   Spotless Mind” director Michel Gondry, who will direct for “Kidding.”
>   Dave Holstein–a writer and producer on both Showtime’s “Weeds” and
>   “I’m Dying Up Here”– created the series, wrote the pilot, and will
>   serve as showrunner. Carrey and Gondry will also executive produce
>   along with Jason Bateman, Raffi Adlan, Jim Garavente, and “I’m Dying
>   Up Here” executive producer Michael Aguilar. http://variety.com/2017/tv/news/jim-carrey-showtime-series-kidding-michael-gondry-1202558804/

Comment: While I don't doubt he's working on a variety of creative projects, I don't think the ones you mention fit the category of Hollywood movies, which is what the question is specifically referring to.

Comment: Although that is true, it was about Hollywood movies, I still felt like the Q was about his "filming" career in general, not seeing him around in the film world generally. Since big names are now also on the small screen--I think "Hollywood" could in some cases then extend itself to premium television or streaming services. People are free to take or leave this answer though, should of the Q only really meant "feature films".